# How to do MVC authentication through custom httpmodule

Tags: model-view-controller, httpmodule

Have a legacy application and from there, my MVC application is called.
I planned to use custom httpmodule [AuthenticationModule class inherites IHttpModule]. In Init, I hooked up BeginRequest and do my FormAuthenication stuff...

```
     private void Application_BeginRequest(Object source, EventArgs e) {

         // Do my own authetication and issue FormAuthentication Ticket
    }
```

In web.config:

```
    <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add name="AuthenticationModule" type="RealProperty.LegacySecurity.AuthenticationModule, RealProperty.LegacySecurity" preCondition="ManagedHandler"/>
    </modules>
```

But my AuthenticationModule never got fire in debug...
(1) Can anyone explain why it isn't got called?
(2) Is it correct to do my authentication in BeginRequest?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have both sections in your Web.config file:

```
<system.web>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="MyAuthenticationModule" type="Ns.To.MyAuthenticationModule, MyAssembly" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>

<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
    <add name="MyAuthenticationModule" type="Ns.To.MyAuthenticationModule, MyAssembly" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```